# How to create model with multiple fields for answers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I created a model `Question` with `question:string` and `answer:string`.

I want to create questions with multiple answers(1-30), but in the db there are only two tables(one for question, one for answer).

For example, I have a field for questions and a lot of fields for answers which I can add dynamically. After that I want to display question and all answers that belongs to it. How do I do this?

Comment: If you have two tables, one `question` and other is `answer`. So you can define relationship betweeen them. question has_many answers and answer belongs_to question. you can refer to this link it has similar example http://iroller.ru/blog/2013/10/14/nested-model-form-in-rails-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `Question` and `Answer` model as

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers 
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end
```

RUn migration

```
rails g migration addQuestionIdToAnswers question_id:integer
```

So now you can say `question.answers` and this will give you all the `answers` which belong to that question. as you have `question_id` field on every `answer'

You can make calls like

```
answer.question # return the question the answer `belongs_to`

question.answers # return all the answers the question `has_many`
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to separate those concerns. 
What I mean is:
Make a separate `Answer` model and migration so you can create an 'answers' table in your database. That way you can put this in your Question model:

```
has_many :answers
```

and in your Answer model:

```
belongs_to :question
```

I'd say this is the proper way to achieve what you are looking for.